# Ignore series in axis limit calculations in highcharter or highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts

I'm adding a regression line to a scatter plot in `highcharter` in R but the same question would apply to highcharts. Since I set the `endOnTick` and `startOnTick` to be TRUE the x and y-axes are extended beyond the scatter plot a bit. This is what I want.

But I would like the regression line I'm adding to extend all the way to the axes. I've considered a few options:

1. Try to compute a line that is exactly the length from tick-to-tick. This is tricky given there will be a range of input data.
2. Try to predict way, way beyond the limits (like -100000 to 1000000), add this as a series and somehow have Highcharts ignore this series in computing the axes limits. I thought this would be the best option but I can't see a way to ignore a series.
3. I also played around with the regression plugin etc but extending the line does not seem to be an option
4. I played around with two x and y axes without success.

**Here is the data setup**

```r
# Create scatter data
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
n <- 5
xvals <- seq(-200, 200, length = n)
dat <- tibble(
  x = xvals,
  y = x + rnorm(n, sd = 100)
)

# Create line data
lm1 <- lm(y~x, dat)
preds <- tibble(
  x = xvals,
  y = predict(lm1, x = xvals)
)
```

**In this plot, where I don't start or end on a tick, the regression line (and the points) extend to the axes**

I do want the line to extend to the axes BUT I want to start and end on a tick for the points.

[image]

```r
highchart() |> 
  hc_add_series(
    dat,
    type = "scatter",
  ) |> 
  hc_add_series(
    preds,
    type = "line"
  )
```

**But if I want the axes to start/end on a tick then there is a gap between the points and the line (as expected)**

But I want the line to extend to the axes

[image]

```r
highchart() |> 
  hc_add_series(
    dat,
    type = "scatter",
  ) |> 
  hc_add_series(
    preds,
    type = "line"
  ) |>
  hc_xAxis(
    endOnTick = TRUE,
    startOnTick = TRUE
  ) |> 
  hc_yAxis(
    endOnTick = TRUE,
    startOnTick = TRUE
  )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, looking at this example, would you like to achieve something like this or completely eliminate the gap between the series and the xaxis? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1fhuez3b/

Comment: I want the line to extend all the way to the axes but leave the gap for points. An example might be (a) plot the points as normal, allow the gap for the ticks; (b) add a regression line where x vals are, essentially, -1 billion to 1 billion (so that, of course, it would hit the axes) BUT force highcharts not to use the line to compute axis limits.

Comment: So it should look like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p0mxwjad/

Comment: Thanks for this! The plot itself looks good in this instance. But it relies on a hard-coded `xExtend` value (0.1) here and I'm not sure if that will work in a range of settings. If I eyeball the data and pick an xExtend value that works such that the line is exactly long enough that it does not change the tick used then it works. But if, say, the nearest tick is 0.3 beyond the points then the line won't extend all the way. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, one way to approach this could be to calculate the xExtend by rounding up to the nearest desired tick interval. This way, no matter the data, the regression line would extend to the nearest tick. This does require knowing or setting the tick interval, which might not be constant across different datasets: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pbhymz3t/